# jQuery image preview before upload script

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

jQuery image preview before upload script does not work when called on multiple items in the same page. I changed the id's on the script so that it can apply to the respective image but it does not work as intended.

I made a JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/6977/

The Code for it:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image1" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp2" />
    <img id="blah2" src="#" alt="your image2" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah2').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp2").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is change the second function readURL to a different name as readURL2
Solved Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luanranufe/66szr4bp/)

It worked for me.

```
  function readURL2(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah2').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp2").change(function(){
    readURL2(this);
});
```

good luck